# How can I pass ']' in to patindex for pattern which contains '%[ ]%'. For eg. PatIndex('%[ ] ]%')

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to remove '[' and ']' using PatIndex.
My code is..

```
@String = 'Hello[ W]orld'
@MatchPattern = '[]'
@MatchPattern =  '%[+@MatchPattern+]%'
Set @ String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')
```

But its not done because it already contains both brackets.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not use REPLACE:  select replace(replace('Hello[ W]orld', ']', ''), '[', '')?

Comment: if you're going to include variables in your statement, please include `DECLARE` statements (and ensure the SQL runs, `SET @ String` isn't valid syntax). Also, where does `@MatchExpression` come from in your `PATINDEX`? It's not previously assigned a value, so the result of that statement will always be *`NULL`* (unless you're assigning it else where, and then we don't know what it is).

Comment: On a different note, if you want to search for a Bracket in a `LIKE` clause, you need to encapsulate them. For example: `SELECT PATINDEX('%[[]%', @String);`. But @MJG is right, `REPLACE` is a much better idea.

Comment: @MJH please post it as an answer so we can vote it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use REPLACE:

```
select replace(replace('Hello[ W]orld', ']', ''), '[', '')
```